# Highcharts not displaying anything just blank html page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I tried to use the example given in highcharts website. But when i use it all i am getting is a blank html page. Someone please help me with the code. I do not understand why the code is not loading properly please tell me if i should add something extra to this, and please do let me know how to use a php array to make this graph work also

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"       type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script>
$(function () {
  var chart;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
            percentageDecimals: 1
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                {
                    name: 'Chrome',
                    y: 12.8,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                },
                ['Safari',    8.5],
                ['Opera',     6.2],
                ['Others',   0.7]
            ]
        }]
    });
});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe your problem is in the order you included the scripts. Try placing jQuery first:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"       type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

Demo ([working](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/2xYSm/) / [not working](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/2xYSm/1/)).

**Update:** to load your data from MySQL using PHP, please see [this example](http://blueflame-software.com/blog/using-highcharts-with-php-and-mysql/). However, as you pointed out yourself, encoding it using JSON might be a better option:

```
$data = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    $data[] = array($row[1], $row[0]);
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

This last `echo` can be used either to return the whole array using ajax (like the linked example above), or when generating the page itself (i.e. "hardcoding" it in the script):

```
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        data: <?php echo json_encode($data)?> 
    }]
```

This will work since your array, when JSON encoded, can be used in place of a JavaScript literal (and the `json_encode` should take care of escaping everything, preventing XSS vulnerabilities).

Comment: and do you know how to take values from mysql using php and passing it onto this ? the formatt of the data from mysql is as follows:   24 Afghanisthan
6 Iran
11 KSA
21 Pakistan
14 UAE

Comment: @user2038580 [this](http://blueflame-software.com/blog/using-highcharts-with-php-and-mysql/) looks like a good resource

Comment: see the query i will be using is :                                      
SELECT SUM( score ) , nationality
FROM details
GROUP BY nationality
LIMIT 0 , 30                                                                          I want to know how to use the value retrieved from here in javascript.

Comment: @user2038580 will you load the chart data using ajax, or include it directly on the page? The resource I linked before shows a full example using PHP, but if you need more help please update your question with the code you have so far.

Comment: i was thinking of getting the value from mysql using php then use json encode and pass it to javascript. I would like to know how to use as associative array and how to give the values to javascript so it can plot the graph. The graph should show the countries based on the score.

Comment: @user2038580 check my updated answer. You can simply create an array (or associative array, or array of arrays, etc) and then call [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on it.

Comment: i tried echoing the encoded array but its not showing the graph now ..can you help

Comment: @user2038580 Are there any errors in the browser console? Also, I'd like to see what your `echo` outputted, please edit your question (or provide a link, if it's too big to put in the question body).

Answer (score 5):

The order of including javascripts should be:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"       type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

By this I mean, you have to include the jQuery library first before any other script.

Comment: and do you know how to take values from mysql using php and passing it onto this ? the formatt of the data from mysql is as follows:   24 Afghanisthan
6 Iran
11 KSA
21 Pakistan
14 UAE

Comment: see the query i will be using is :                                      
SELECT SUM( score ) , nationality
FROM details
GROUP BY nationality
LIMIT 0 , 30                                                                          I want to know how to use the value retrieved from here in javascript.